# Como puedo guardar un Array en el localStorage

Tags: php, javascript, array, objeto, local-storage

Hola buenas tardes estoy tratando de guardar un array de objetos en el localStorage, estoy intentando guardar datos de un anuncio -> descripción, ruta de imagen, titulo, al momento que agrego un anuncio nuevo me reemplaza los datos del anterior guardado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los datos en local storage se almacenan clave-valor, si guardas un nuevo dato con la misma clave vas a reemplazar el valor previo con el nuevo. Almacena un array de anuncios y no un anuncio, vas recuperando los datos y añadiendo un nuevo anuncio antes de volver a guardar.
Añade tu código como texto y trata de explicar mejor tu problema.

Comment: Al leer tu pregunta, y viendo que ya está respondida tu duda, te plantearía lo siguiente: ¿realmente te interesa almacenar toda la información del favorito? ¿O podrías sólo guardar algún identificador (no sé si será posible por la lógica de tu app/requisitos)? Ten en cuenta que el localStorage suele tener una capacidad, que aunque pueda parecer elevada para almacenar información en formato cadena, debes tenerlo presente para un correcto escalado de tu app.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes guardar directamente un array en localStorage.

Lo que si puedes hacer es guardar un array en string con JSON.stringify.

Guardar en localStorage:

```
let miArray = ["a", "b"];
localStorage.setItem("array1", JSON.stringify(miArray));
```

Para obtener el array guardado usa JSON.parse

```
let arrayRecojido = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array1"));
console.log(arrayRecojido[0]); // "a"
console.log(arrayRecojido[1]); // "b"
```

Además, debes de saber:

- Los datos guardados en localStorage nunca expiran, para borrarlos tendrás que usar `localStorage.removeItem("array1")`

**Además**

Si necesitas guardar un objeto en localStorage, usa el mismo código, pero cambiando el array por un objecto

Guardar en localStorage:

```
let miObj = {"a":"b"};
localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(miObj));
```

Para obtener el objeto guardado usa JSON.parse

```
let recojido = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("obj"));
console.log(recojido.a); // "b"
```